# Can't use Wifi when Ethernet is Active

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ethernet

I'm not able to use Ethernet and Wifi Simultaneously on Windows 7.

I've read that it is supposed to be default in Win7, but when I connect the Ethernet, I can't connect to WiFi.  A pop-up comes up showing that I'm already connected to Ethernet, like it is saying, "Hey, why do you want to connect to Wifi when you've got a perfectly good Ethernet connection right here?!".

I've tried enabling via the command prompt and I get the error "WLAN auto configuration is disabled on adapter", though when I do ipconfig /all, it states that WLAN Auto Config is actually enabled.

I've already tried the automatic metric technique, putting the Wifi as 1 and the Ethernet as 2, but it hasn't made any impact.

My goal is to have the Wifi ForceBind to a single app, and run the rest of my internet off the ethernet.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to check BIOS settings for any possible options there. Also, have you tried connecting to the wifi first and then plugging in the Ethernet cable?

Comment: This is NOT how Windows normally works..  Both adapters should work fine.  What software is causing the pop-up?  Does your system come with manufacturer utilities that help with network switching?  To that end -- Have you tried Windows in Safe Mode with Networking? Does it behave the same way?  What if you disable all non-MS start-ups and services via MSconfig and then boot normally - does it still act the same way?

Comment: I'm with @Wally. I've had more than one system factory-configured to cut of WiFi when a cable was connected, both through BIOS and with networking software installed by Dell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the answers.  I'm pretty sure it is Symantec End Point Protection.  I found an article where they tell Network Admins how to prevent this very thing.  And I work for a big company, so it seems to me that fits the bill.  I think I'm SOL.

Comment: Can you not ask your admins to make such a change for you? Squeaky wheel gets the grease. Maybe you're not the only one with that problem, since it's a corporate-issue device.