# Windows 7: Configuring wired LAN connection to supercede Wifi

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet

CONTEXT

Acer Aspire D255E configured with Win7.  WiFi trumps Ethernet connection when both are engaged.  In order to use the wired LAN connection, the WiFi must be disabled.  When this laptop is running Ubuntu, LAN trumps WiFi as expected: therefore not a hardware issue.

GOAL

When Ethernet is connected, WiFi takes a back seat: likewise when Ethernet is disconnected, WiFi is engaged

QUESTION

How is WiFi configured to be secondary to Ethernet?

Comment: You can do it by manually assigning metrics. See [this](http://superuser.com/q/1039470/238539) question and my answer.

Comment: @VL-80: Intruiging! This seems to configure prioritization.  When the machine is faced with sending out traffic, will the metric prioritization be followed?

Comment: It should. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrics_(networking)): `Metrics are used to determine whether one route should be chosen over another`.

Comment: @DavidPostill:  are edits done manually or are they done by some clever automation?

Comment: @gatorback Semi-manually. I have a spell checker ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: I wonder if automating your editing process to process all new posts with a spellcheck engine is possible and if it would double your remarkable 'score'.

Comment: @gatorback I don't get rep (any more) from editing posts.

Answer (score 0):

- Go the Start Menu and type Network Connections and hit Enter
- In the Network Connections window press the Alt key to make the menu bar appear at the top
- Choose Advanced and go to Advanced Settings
- In the Advanced Settings window you'll see a list of Connections along with arrow keys to the right that allows you to modify the preference order of your available connections. Move your wireless adapter to the top of the list.

[image]

Comment: Attempts with LAN and wifi at the top of the list were unsuccessful: rebooted each time to test.  Suggestions please?  Very well written and double bonus points for screenshot

Comment: This is/should be the default behavior though

Comment: @JourneymanGeek:  Agreed. In my experience a live LAN connect event disengages active wifi.  The system is dual boot and exhibits this expected behavior with Ubuntu

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  Thought this was interesting: http://superuser.com/questions/722963/cant-use-wifi-when-ethernet-is-active?rq=1